# Limiting utilized area within textbox using CSS

Tags: css, textbox

I have a small image placed within the right side of my text box and I am trying to prevent my text from running behind that image. However, I do not want to limit the amount of characters by doing this. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="searchContainer">
        <!--Search Bar-->
        <input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Type here to search" onfocus="placeholder = ' '"/>
        <!--Microphone-->
        <img  id="mic" src="*Super long URL*"/>
    </div>

/*Search Bar*/
#searchBar {
opacity: 0.6;
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 24px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
width: 550px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What people typically do is put the text input, and image inside of a container. They remove the border of the input so it appears to be a white input box. They stylize the container with a border and such to make it look like THAT is the input.  Then they put the (in your case) microphone image floated to the right, and add a margin right to the input. so the text does not hide behind the image.

Here is the basic idea: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJdMJB

HTML:

```
<div id="searchContainer">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w5j4E5O.png"/>
  <input id="searchBar" type="text"/>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#searchBar {
opacity: 0.6;
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 24px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
width: 500px;
border:none;

}
#searchContainer{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  width:520px;
}
img{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is an image inside the text area. I'm assuming  I could make the textbox invisible, pad it, then create a border around .searchContainer to mimic what was the outline of the textbox to achieve this. I was just curious if there was a more direct way to keep text from running the full length of the textbox.

Comment: Oh. you don't mean a textarea tag. In HTML textarea is a specific tag, and you cannot put images in it.  Hence my confusion. Quick question. Why are you removing the placeholder text onfocus? The whole point of placeholder is you don't have to do that.

Comment: I apologize if my wording is confusing. This is still all very new to me. I guess I meant the image is on top of it (visually perceived as inside it). I actually just found my solution by adding padding-left: 30px and changing the width: from 550px to 520px.

And for your question, I pose another question: Is there a better way to place text in the box until it is clicked? I had to include the onfocus bit because the placeholder text still sat in the box after being clicked.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for your help!